# TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. Did i do anything wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a h1 with JavaScript and it gives me this error:

```js
TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

The code:

```js
function append(child) {
  document.body.appendChild(child);
};

const title = React.createElement(
  'h1',
  null,
  'Hello World',
);
append(title);
console.log(header);
```

Comment: Just for what it's worth: You *don't* put a `;` at the end of a function declaration (like your `append`). You *do* put a semicolon at the ends of statements (like your two function calls at the end) if the statement doesn't have an attached block. (Unless you're relying on Automatic Semicolon Insertion, which some people like to do. Regardless of whether you do or don't, it's important to know the relevant rules and follow them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React elements are not DOM elements, so you can't use them with `appendChild`.

You'll want to either use the DOM directly **or** use React, but usually not both (or at least, typically in a React project the amount of direct DOM manipulation you do is fairly minimal).

Here's that code using the DOM (no React):

```
function append(child) {
    document.body.appendChild(child);
}

const title = document.createElement("h1");
title.textContent = "Hello world";
append(title);
console.log(title); // Changed `header` to `title`, you have no `header` element in the code
```

Doing the same with React, you wouldn't typically have an `append` function like yours. You'd have a **single** call to `ReactDOM.render` in the entire project (usually) that mounted your top-level React component in a DOM element; everything else would be rendered by React as part of handling the component logic.